# Spark 2.0 standalone mode collect() error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-standalone

I'm working on Spark2.0(scala) and Play framework.I'm running this  standalone mode application with Intellij IDEA. My application works just fine with local master

```
object Utilities {

  val master = "local"
  //-------machine learning algorithm
  val modelFolder = "Model"    
  val linearModel = "LinearRegression"
  val logisticModel = "LogisticRegression"
  val kmeansModel = "Kmeans"
  val decisionTreeModel = "DecisionTree"
}
```

but when I switch to standalone cluster mode it didn't work

```
object Utilities {
val master = "spark://ubuntu:7077"
//-------machine learning algorithm
  val modelFolder = "Model"
  val linearModel = "LinearRegression"
  val logisticModel = "LogisticRegression"
  val kmeansModel = "Kmeans"
  val decisionTreeModel = "DecisionTree"
}
```

I tried all my code on the cluster mode spark-shell and everything was fine.
I tried to find what is wrong with my code and found that every rdd.map.collect action just failed

This is where my application failed

SimpleCompute.scala

```
var tick = convertDF.rdd.map(row => row.getDouble(0))
var mean =tick.collect()
```

Regression.scala

```
val residualArr = residuals.rdd.map(r => Math.round(r(0).toString.toDouble * 1000.0) / 1000.0).collect
val resStr = "[" + residualArr.mkString(",") + "]"


val predictArr = trainingSummary.predictions.select("prediction").rdd.map(r => Math.round(r(0).toString.toDouble * 1000.0) / 1000.0).collect
val predStr = "[" + predictArr.mkString(",") + "]"


val labelArr = trainingSummary.predictions.select("label").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect()
var labelStr = "[" + labelArr.mkString(",") + "]"
```

I get this ERROR message

```
[error]o.a.s.s.TaskSetManager - Task 0 in stage 20.0 failed 4 times;     aborting job
(org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 20.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 20.0 (TID 24, 10.211.55.8): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  controllers.util.SimpleCompute$$anonfun$4
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and this

```
[error] o.a.s.s.TaskSetManager - Task 0 in stage 24.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
error in Linear Regressionorg.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 24.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 24.0 (TID 34, 10.211.55.8): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   controllers.Regression$$anonfun$callRegression$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$1
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
```

Please help me with this problem.

spark:2.0.0

scala:2.11.8

PLAY:2.5.X

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: still working on it